# how to release object from thid party dll?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i'm developing a program to convert RTF to html
i'm using the DLLs found here
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx?fid=1458864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3427424&fr=1#xx0xx

this dll saves a jpg file from html to a specific folder,
when i run the program, it cinverts the rtf for the first time and saves the images to the folder perfectly
but when i try to convert it again i hace this error
"error a generic error occured in GDI+"
i think this dll use SaveImage method and to avoid this you must release the Image object you created but i can't modify the DLL,
is there is any way to release the object i've created from this dll?
this is my code

```
RtfVisualImageAdapter imageAdapter = new RtfVisualImageAdapter(
    @Application.StartupPath + "\\Program Data\\temp\\{0}{1}",
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
RtfImageConvertSettings imageConvertSettings = 
    new RtfImageConvertSettings(imageAdapter);
RtfImageConverter imageConverter = new RtfImageConverter(imageConvertSettings);

try
{
    IRtfDocument rtfDocument = RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc(
        ConversionText, imageConverter);
    RtfHtmlConverter htmlConverter = new RtfHtmlConverter(rtfDocument);
    htmlConverter.Settings.ConvertVisualHyperlinks = true;
    htmlConverter.Settings.UseNonBreakingSpaces = true;
    this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl2.Text = htmlConverter.Convert();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, "Error " + exception.Message, this.Text, 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is sloppy, it doesn't call the Dispose() method on the bitmap after saving it.  That keeps a lock on the file, GDI+ uses a memory-mapped file to avoid putting pressure on the paging file.  Important because bitmaps can be quite large.  Trying to save to the same file again fails because of the lock.  GDI+ exception messages are notoriously sloppy as well.

I think the bug is located in Interpreter\Converter\Image\RtfImageConverter.cs, SaveImage() method.  The "convertedImage" bitmap doesn't get disposed.  Note that the Graphics object in that same method doesn't get disposed either.  Fix it by wrapping them with the using statement.

Run this code through FxCop to catch similar mistakes.  And ask yourself if you *really* want to maintain code like this.

Comment: thanks for your reply nobugz, 
'Itenso.Rtf.Converter.Image.RtfImageConvertSettings': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' this is the error i get when trying to wrap them with the using statement. i can't get over this.
sorry but what do you mean with "ask yourself if you really want to maintain code like this."

Comment: You put it in the wrong place.  Not sure what you did, instead just call convertedImage.Dispose() after the Save() call.

Answer (score 0):

If something implements `IDisposable`, you can call its `Dispose()` method.  Objects are eligible for garbage collection as soon as they go out of scope so you might also try calling `GC.Collect()` after there are no more references to the object you want "released."

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the source code you could examine it and figure out where it keeps a reference and make sure it's released.

If you cannot figure out where to do this you could load the code up in a separate [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), and execute your code there. When you are finished you can unload the AppDomain, and your application will release any objects. Then recreate the AppDomain for the next run.

But I would try to spend some time figuring out the real issue before using AppDomains.

And another thing. Do you get the GDI error when you execute the same file twice, or two different files in succession? It could be that it fails to load the image of the second file and gives you the error.

Comment: "If you cannot figure out where to do this you could load the code up in a separate AppDomain, and execute your code there. When you are finished you can unload the AppDomain, and your application will release any objects. Then recreate the AppDomain for the next run."
sorry but i can't understand this.

"And another thing. Do you get the GDI error when you execute the same file twice, or two different files in succession? It could be that it fails to load the image of the second file and gives you the error."

the error is that the file is being used by another application or program
thanks,

Comment: Your questions states the error to be: "error a generic error occured in GDI+", which don't have to mean it's being used by another process. Or are you getting another error as well? As for appdomains read up on the link I provided to get you started. AppDomains are for example very useful for COM components which you want to unload, since it's basically the only way to unload a resource.

Comment: Creating and releasing appDomains are not as trivial as it sounds. But does releasing the AppDomain also release unmanaged resources?

Comment: @Asher, yes it will. I've used it previously with third party COM compontents which were unstable and had to be released. And you are right that it's not trivial, but it's not very hard either once you get the hang of it :)

Answer (score 0):

As Max sez. Or better use the using construct. NEVER call GC.Collect unless you are dead sure by doing so you'll free a few GB or RAM!

Comment: the using construct give me error that an object that doesn't implement dispose method can't be in a using construct

Comment: Then the classes don't implement the IDispose interface, you can't do anything without access to the code, check the code with reflector and try to see if you can emulate the error. Are you sure your path to the image is correct and your process has access there?